# Defines compilation order

Tags: c, compilation, include

Assume the following files:

inner.h

```
#define SIZE 1

int getValue(void);
```

inner.c

```
#include "inner.h"
static int value = SIZE;

int getValue(void)
{
    return value;
}
```

outer.h

```
#include "inner.h"

#ifdef SIZE
#undef SIZE
#define SIZE 2
#endif

int getValue2(void);
```

outer.c

```
#include "outer.h"
static int value2 = SIZE;

int getValue2(void)
{
    return value2;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "inner.h"
#include "outer.h"

int main (void)
{
    printf("value = %i, value2 = %i, getValue(), getValue2());
}
```

In the compiled code, will

1. `value` be equal to 1 or 2, since `inner` will be compiled before `outer`?
2. `value2` be equal to 1 or 2?
3. What will be printed by printf?

Comment: `inner.c` never includes `outer.h` (directly or indirectly). So the only `SIZE` definition that is relevant is the one in `inner.h`. If there is still any doubt then just tell the compiler to produce preprocessed output to get the exact value (`-E` option if using `gcc`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited my question a bit.

Comment: Your example is still not correct I would guess. You have not shown any code that includes `outer.h`. Which means that files is irrelevant. Anyway, the general rule is that the last definition in the file wins.

Comment: It's irrelevant what `main.c` includes. Think of `#define` as a text replacement in the file that it occurs. So in this case the replacement is done inside the `inner.c` file. And the `outer.c` file will get a compilation error as it has no definition of `SIZE`. I think you may be not understanding preprocessing vs compilation vs linking.

Comment: `outer.c` was missing the `outer.h' include. Now it should be correct.

Comment: The last `#define` is always the one that applies. So `1` in inner.c and `2` in outer.c.

Comment: What stops you from trying? And you could also let the compiler output the preprocessed source, for GCC it is the option `-E`. -- Or are you asking what the standard defines? Then, why don't you look into the standard? -- I'm missing some effort on your side.

Comment: Ok, this is what I was wondering about- that even though there is a final define value in the end, the values in the code are different depending on the compilation order. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What matters for pre-processor expansion is *translation units*. A translation unit being a .c file and all the headers it includes. Each such translation unit will have its own expansion of the macro `SIZE`.

In your case, you have:

- inner.c and inner.h forms one translation unit. Here `SIZE` is 1.
- outer.c, outer.h and inner.h forms one translation unit.

  As a first step outer.h will replace `#include "inner.h"` with `#define SIZE 1` and so on. So `SIZE` is defined when it hits `#ifdef SIZE`, after which it will get undef:ed and re-defined. After pre-processing, `SIZE` will therefore be replaced with 2 in this translation unit.

  (Each include means that the contents of the included file gets "recursively" pre-processed, see the chapter "translation phases" of the standard for details).
- main.c, stdio.h, inner.h and outer.h forms one translation unit.

  Here you have `inner.h` included multiple times: both from main.c and indirectly from outer.h. That's why we use include guards in all headers, though it doesn't matter in this specific case.

  `SIZE` will be 2 in this translation unit too, though it isn't used anywhere, so it doesn't matter.

---

> value be equal to 1 or 2, since inner will be compiled before outer?

`1` since `SIZE` is 1 in the translation unit where the definition of `getValue()` is located. Compilation order doesn't matter.

> value2 be equal to 1 or 2?

`2` since `SIZE` is 2 in the translation unit where the definition of `getValue2()` is located. Compilation order doesn't matter.

> What will be printed by printf?

Build it and see for yourself.